# Chrome extension for managing bookmark tree

Tags: chrome, bookmark

I have never really used bookmarks, but I would like to start! I would like to be able to create sublinks under a parent bookmark for each site. Bookmark trees. For example:

```
parent                            -       child
productivity.stackexhange.com     -       /question/ask
```

Is there any such tool that you know of?

Comment: I'm not a Chrome user, but I assume you can make folders in your bookmark tree like in any other browser. Create a folder `productivity.stackexhange.com`, and put your bookmarks in there. No extension required.

Comment: Note that you are approaching this from the wrong direction. First start learning [how to use Chrome bookmarks](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/188842?hl=en). Then if you want more than what's available by default, ask for a tool.

Comment: I am aware one could manually organize by hierarchy, but that is not what I am after. I want to just to bookmark, then have it automatically order by long URLs by the site they belong to(or automatically create a parent bookmark if it does not already exist) then furthermore have the option to manually assign the paren sites to directories, which would further seperate concerns when searching. I would also like to be able to search bookmarks using the url/omnibar. 

I have looked at the native functionality and I do not believe this is exists by default. Thank you, regardless.

Comment: Please update your question with that information. It is obviously not complete.